# Get path from firestore.DocumentRefence

Tags: javascript, python, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to get from a document reference and a collections reference the path that it points to?

when you create a document reference you do something like:
`db.document('your/document/reference/path')`
and you get in return a DocumentReference instance `<class 'google.cloud.firestore_v1beta1.document.DocumentReference'>`

I need it in reverse I have `<class 'google.cloud.firestore_v1beta1.document.DocumentReference'>` and I want to get the path `your/document/refence/path`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out,
so if someone else find himself in this problem:

Let `obj` be of type DocumentReference, and `db` of type Client

then `obj._document_path` returns the full path of the document

and for me, I needed only the last part of the path
so this did the job:

```
path = obj._document_path.replace(db._database_string, '')
```

Comment: _document_path is undefined on a DocumentReference. Has this changed since 2/2018? How do we get the doc ref path now?

Comment: These are the versions I'm currently using, and I can find the path.
`firebase-admin==2.7.0
google-cloud-firestore==0.29.0`

You should get a Document Reference and pull it from there.
I highly recommend using iPython and trying to see what is missing in your process, If you want, publish here your code so I'll be able to see.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :-) I was able to get the DocRef path in docRef.ref.segments[1]. 0 is the collection name, 1 is the Id.

Answer (score 17):

The proper way to get a documents' path:

**From [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.html):**
.path

> e.g. `var path = ref.path`

**From [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.html):**
.ref.path

> e.g. `var path = doc.ref.path`

Answer (score 0):

so i searched for a while because i use references alot in my program... & i couldnt really find any documentation even on the firebase site

so lets say you have a document reference object

```
<google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentReference object at 0x000002702347EC5610>

if you know what collection you can put
getOriUser = db.collection(u'Users').document(DocumentReference.id)
OriUser = getOriUser.get()
Ori= OriUser.to_dict()
```